# Node.js not reading HTML POST request

Tags: html, node.js, postman

My node.js script is receiving HTML POST request calls from the google Chrome extension Postman but it's not seeing the key-value pairs.  Keeps giving me

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
   at app.get.params.QueueUrl (/home/ec2-user/Outfitr/Server/index.js:45:53)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ec2-user/Outfitr/Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at next (/home/ec2-user/Outfitr/Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:110:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/ec2-user/Outfitr/Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:91:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ec2-user/Outfitr/Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at /home/ec2-user/Outfitr/Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:267:22
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/ec2-user/Outfitr/Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
    at next (/home/ec2-user/Outfitr/Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
    at serveStatic (/home/ec2-user/Outfitr/Server/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:59:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ec2-user/Outfitr/Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
```

Here's my code.  Let me know if you need anything else

```
app.post('/bscreateuser', function(request, response) {
  process.stdout.write("Attempted to create a --- BBBSSSSS ---- user  |  ");
  process.stdout.write("request is " + request.url);
  process.stdout.write("username is " + request.body.username);
  process.stdout.write("Password is " + request.body.password);
  bscreateUser(request.query.username, request.body.password);
  response.send('Success' );
});

function bscreateUser(username, password) {
  messageBody = 'create_user("' + username + '","' + password + '")';
  queueUrl = DAO_QUEUE_URL;
  // sys.puts("--- going for BS ---");
  sendSQSMessage(JSON.stringify(messageBody), queueUrl);
}
```

Comment: SUGGESTION: Look at the actual HTTP content.  There are many ways to do this, including [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), [Telerek Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4) and the [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) Developer Tools

Comment: Shouldn't `request.query.username` be `request.body.username`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 bscreateUser(request.query.username, request.body.password);
```

Should be:

```
 bscreateUser(request.body.username, request.body.password);
```

A good way to avoid this in the future is:

```
var body = request.body;
var username = body.username;
var password = body.password
```

And then just use the var username and var password in your code, much less error prone and a little more readable!

Comment: And an even better way to solve these kinds of problems is to familiarize yourself with Node/HTTP debugging tools.  SUGGESTIONS:  [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), [Telerek Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4), [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/).  See also [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) and the [Joyent](http://www.joyent.com/developers/node/debug) "Debug" page.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!